# Generic data structures in C

Tags: c, linked-list, generics, vectors, c89

I'm new to C, and I thought a great way to learn would be to implement some generic data structures and algorithms. So far I've implemented a linked list and a dynamic array. Both are generic, the linked list with void*s and the dynamic array with macros. Both have some straightforward tests in Unity. Both compile with no warnings with the flags:

`-std=c89 -ansi -pedantic`

Let me know what you think!

dynamic_array.h

```
/*
 * A generic dynamic array implemented from scratch in C89.
 *
 * Define a dynamic array through the macro 'DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY(T)'. Put this
 * in your code to define a dynamic array called 'DynamicArray_T' that holds
 * type 'T'. For example: 'DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY(float)' will define a dynamic
 * array called 'DynamicArray_float' that holds floats. This macro will also
 * define all the dynamic array operations as well. These include:
 *   - dynamic_array_T_construct(~)
 *   - dynamic_array_T_destruct(~)
 *   - dynamic_array_T_add(~)
 *   - dynamic_array_T_add_at(~)
 *   - dynamic_array_T_remove(~)
 *   - dynamic_array_T_remove_at(~)
 *   - dynamic_array_T_contains(~)
 * Different types of Dynamic arrays can be defined in the same file. Their
 * types and operations are differentiated by the 'T' in their names.
 * See the macros that define these operations below for their docs.
 * The initial capacity of the array and when it expands/contracts, and by how
 * much, are defined in the constants below.
 *
 * Written by Max Hanson, June 2019.
 */

#ifndef DYNAMIC_ARRAY_H
#define DYNAMIC_ARRAY_H

#include <stdlib.h>

static const int INIT_CAPACITY = 10; /* Initial capacity. */
static const float EXPANSION_POINT = 1.0; /* load > this -> array expands */
static const float CONTRACTION_POINT = 0.3; /* load < this -> array contracts */
/* Expanded capacity = this * old capacity */
static const float EXPANSION_FACTOR = 2.0;
/* Contracted capacity = this * old capacity */
static const float CONTRACTION_FACTOR = 0.5;

/*
 * Macro to define a dynamic array of type T and its operations.
 *
 * A type parameter 'T' is valid if, and only if:
 *   - It contains no spaces. Note this means pointers must be typecast.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY(T)                                                \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_STRUCT(T)                                             \
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_HELPERS(T)                                           \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_CTOR(T)                                               \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_DTOR(T)                                               \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_ADD(T)                                                \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_ADD_AT(T)                                             \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_REMOVE(T)                                             \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_REMOVE_AT(T)                                          \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_CONTAINS(T)                                           \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_EXPAND(T)                                             \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_CONTRACT(T)                                           \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_INSERT_ELEM(T)                                        \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_DELETE_ELEM(T)                                        \
    DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_RECALC_LOAD(T)

/*
 * A generic dynamic array.
 *
 * A dynamic array is valid if, and only if:
 *   - Its size is how many elements it contains.
 *   - Its capacity is how large the internal array is.
 *   - Its load is its size divided by its capacity.
 *   - All of its elements are consecutive and start at index 0.
 * The constructor is guaranteed to return a valid dynamic array and each
 * operation will keep a valid dynamic array valid.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_STRUCT(T)                                         \
    typedef struct DynamicArrayTag_##T                                          \
    {                                                                           \
        float load;                                                             \
        int size;                                                               \
        int capacity;                                                           \
        T *array;                                                               \
    } DynamicArray_##T;

/*
 * Create an empty dynamic array on the heap.
 *
 * The initial array capacity is defined in a constant at the top of the file.
 *
 * Every case complexity: BIG-THETA( malloc() ).
 * If:
 *   - The type 'T' supplied to the definition macro is valid.
 * Then:
 *   - A pointer to a valid dynamic array is returned.
 *   - The size and load of the array will be 0.
 *   - The capacity will be initialized according to the constants above.
 *   - The elements of the internal array will be random.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If there is an error allocating either the internal array or the dynamic
 *     array instance, then null will be returned.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_CTOR(T)                                           \
    DynamicArray_##T *dynamic_array_##T##_construct()                           \
    {                                                                           \
        T *array;                                                               \
                                                                                \
        DynamicArray_##T *self = malloc(sizeof(DynamicArray_##T));           \
        array = malloc(INIT_CAPACITY * sizeof(T));                              \
        if (self == NULL || array == NULL)                                   \
        {                                                                       \
            return NULL;                                                        \
        }                                                                       \
        self->array = array;                                                 \
                                                                                \
        self->capacity = INIT_CAPACITY;                                      \
        self->size = 0;                                                      \
        self->load = 0;                                                      \
    }

/*
 * Free all memory associated with a dynamic array.
 *
 * Every case complexity: BIG-THETA( free() ).
 * If:
 *   - The dynamic array is valid.
 * Then:
 *   - All memory associated with the dynamic array will be deallocated.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_DTOR(T)                                           \
    void dynamic_array_##T##_destruct(DynamicArray_##T *self)                \
    {                                                                           \
        free(self->array);                                                   \
        free(self);                                                          \
    }

/*
 * Add an element to the end of a dynamic array.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O( n + malloc() + free() ). N: size of the array.
 * Amortized complexity: O(1).
 * If:
 *   - The dynamic array is valid.
 * Then:
 *   - The new element is added onto the end of the array and 0 is returned.
 *   - The arrays size will be incremented.
 *   - The arrays load factor will be recalculated.
 *   - If the array is full, then it will be expanded to hold the new element.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If the array is full and reallocation fails (no more memory), then 1
 *     is returned and the array is not altered.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_ADD(T)                                            \
    int dynamic_array_##T##_add(DynamicArray_##T *self, T elem)              \
    {                                                                           \
        return dynamic_array_##T##_insert_elem(self, elem, self->size);   \
    }

/*
 * Add an element at the i-th index of a dynamic array.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O( n + malloc() + free() ) to expand the array.
 *   N: size of the array.
 * Amortized complexity: O(1).
 * If:
 *   - The dynamic array is valid.
 * Then:
 *   - The element will be the new i-th element of the array.
 *   - The arrays size will be incremented.
 *   - The arrays load factor will be recalculated.
 *   - If the array is full, then it will be expanded to hold the new element.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If the array is full and reallocation fails (no more memory), then 1
 *     is returned and the array is not altered.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_ADD_AT(T)                                         \
    int dynamic_array_##T##_add_at(DynamicArray_##T *self, T elem, int i)    \
    {                                                                           \
        return dynamic_array_##T##_insert_elem(self, elem, i);               \
    }

/*
 * Remove the first occurrence of an element in the array.
 *
 * Worst case complexity: O( n + malloc() + free() ) to contract the array.
 *   N: number of elements in the array.
 * Best case complexity: O(1) to remove the last element.
 * Average case complexity: O(n) to remvoe an intermediate element.
 * If:
 *   - The dynamic array is valid.
 * Then:
 *   - The first occurence of the element is removed from the array and all
 *     elements after it are moved one index down.
 *   - The size of the array is decremented.
 *   - The load factor of the array is recalculated.
 *   - If the load is small enough (see constants), then the array is contracted.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If the array is contracted and there is an error allocating the new array,
 *     then 1 is returned and the original array is not modified.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_REMOVE(T)                                         \
    int dynamic_array_##T##_remove(DynamicArray_##T *self, T elem)           \
    {                                                                           \
        int idx;                                                                \
                                                                                \
        for (idx = 0; idx < self->size; idx++)                               \
        {                                                                       \
            if ((self->array)[idx] == elem)                                  \
            {                                                                   \
                return dynamic_array_##T##_delete_elem(self, idx);           \
            }                                                                   \
        }                                                                       \
        return 0;                                                               \
    }

/*
 * Remove the i-th element in the array.
 *
 * Worst case complexity: O( n + malloc() + free() ) to contract the array.
 *   N: number of elements in the array.
 * Best case complexity: O(1) to remove the last element.
 * Average case complexity: O(n) to remvoe an intermediate element.
 * If:
 *   - The dynamic array is valid.
 * Then:
 *   - The i-th element is removed from the array and all elements after it
 *     are moved one index down.
 *   - The size of the array is decremented.
 *   - The load factor of the array is recalculated.
 *   - If the load is small enough (see constants), then the array is contracted.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If the array is contracted and there is an error allocating the new array,
 *     then 1 is returned and the original array is not modified.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_REMOVE_AT(T)                                      \
    int dynamic_array_##T##_remove_at(DynamicArray_##T *self, int i)         \
    {                                                                           \
        return dynamic_array_##T##_delete_elem(self, i);                     \
    }

/*
 * Determine if the array contains an element.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O(n).
 * If:
 *   - The dynamic array is valid
 * Then:
 *   - If the array contains the element, then 1 is returned. If it does not,
 *     then 0 is returned.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_CONTAINS(T)                                       \
    int dynamic_array_##T##_contains(DynamicArray_##T *self, T elem)         \
    {                                                                           \
        int idx;                                                                \
        T *array;                                                               \
                                                                                \
        array = self->array;                                                 \
        for (idx = 0; idx < self->size; idx++)                               \
        {                                                                       \
            if (array[idx] == elem)                                             \
            {                                                                   \
                return 1;                                                       \
            }                                                                   \
        }                                                                       \
        return 0;                                                               \
    }

/*
 * Declare signatures of helper methods.
 */
#define DECLARE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_HELPERS(T)                                       \
    static int dynamic_array_##T##_expand(DynamicArray_##T *self);           \
    static int dynamic_array_##T##_contract(DynamicArray_##T *self);         \
    static int dynamic_array_##T##_insert_elem(DynamicArray_##T *self,       \
                                               T elem, int i);                  \
    static int dynamic_array_##T##_delete_elem(DynamicArray_##T *self,       \
                                               int rem_idx);                    \
    static void dynamic_array_##T##_recalc_load(DynamicArray_##T *self);     \

/*
 * Expand the array.
 *
 * The capacity of the new array is defined in the EXPANSION_FACTOR constant
 * at the top if this file.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O( n + malloc() + free() ). N: size of array.
 * If:
 *   - The array is valid.
 * Then:
 *   - A new, expanded array is allocated.
 *   - All elements in the dynamic array are copied to this new array.
 *   - The dynamic arrays internal array is swapped with this new array.
 *   - 0 is returned.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If there is an error allocating the new array, then 1 is returned. and
 *     the old array is not modified.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_EXPAND(T)                                         \
    static int dynamic_array_##T##_expand(DynamicArray_##T *self)            \
    {                                                                           \
        T *new_array;                                                           \
        int new_capacity;                                                       \
        int idx;                                                                \
                                                                                \
        /* Allocate new array. */                                               \
        new_capacity = EXPANSION_FACTOR * (self->capacity);                  \
        new_array = malloc(new_capacity * sizeof(T));                           \
        if (new_array == NULL)                                                  \
        {                                                                       \
            /* Return and do not alter original array. */                       \
            return 1;                                                           \
        }                                                                       \
                                                                                \
        /* Copy elements over and swap arrays. */                               \
        for (idx = 0; idx <= self->size; idx++)                              \
        {                                                                       \
            new_array[idx] = self->array[idx];                               \
        }                                                                       \
        free(self->array);                                                   \
        self->array = new_array;                                             \
                                                                                \
        self->capacity = new_capacity;                                       \
        dynamic_array_##T##_recalc_load(self);                               \
                                                                                \
        return 0;                                                               \
    }

/*
 * Contract the array.
 *
 * The capacity of the new array is defined in the CONTRACTION_FACTOR constant
 * at the top if this file.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O( n + malloc() + free() ). N: size of array.
 * If:
 *   - The array is valid.
 * Then:
 *   - A new, contracted array is allocated.
 *   - All elements in the dynamic array are copied to this new array.
 *   - The dynamic arrays internal array is swapped with this new array.
 *   - 0 is returned.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If there is an error allocating the new array, then 1 is returned and the
 *     old array is not modified.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_CONTRACT(T)                                       \
    static int dynamic_array_##T##_contract(DynamicArray_##T *self)          \
    {                                                                           \
        T *new_array;                                                           \
        int new_capacity;                                                       \
        int idx;                                                                \
                                                                                \
        /* Allocate new array. */                                               \
        new_capacity = CONTRACTION_FACTOR * self->capacity;                  \
        new_array = malloc(new_capacity * sizeof(T));                           \
        if (new_array == NULL)                                                  \
        {                                                                       \
            /* Return error and leave old array unmodified. */                  \
            return 1;                                                           \
        }                                                                       \
                                                                                \
        /* Copy elements over and swap arrays. */                               \
        for (idx = 0; idx <= self->size; idx++)                              \
        {                                                                       \
            new_array[idx] = self->array[idx];                               \
        }                                                                       \
        free(new_array);                                                        \
        self->array = new_array;                                             \
                                                                                \
        self->capacity = new_capacity;                                       \
        dynamic_array_##T##_recalc_load(self);                               \
                                                                                \
        return 0;                                                               \
    }

/*
 * Insert an element at the i-th index of a dynamic array.
 * Helper methods for add, add_at operations.
 * 
 * Worst case complexity: O(n + malloc() + free() ) to expand the array.
 *   N: size of array.
 * Best case complexity: O(1) to add to the end of the array.
 * If:
 *   - The dynamic array is valid.
 *   - 0 <= i <= self->size.
 * Then:
 *   - The element will be the new i-th element in the dynamic array.
 *   - The dynamic arrays size will be incremented.
 *   - The dynamic arrays load factor will be recalculated.
 *   - If the dynamic array is full, then it will be expanded.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If the dynamic array is full and there is an error expanding it, then 1
 *     is returned.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_INSERT_ELEM(T)                                    \
static int dynamic_array_##T##_insert_elem(DynamicArray_##T *self, T elem,   \
                                           int i)                               \
{                                                                               \
    int idx;                                                                    \
    int status;                                                                 \
    T *array;                                                                   \
                                                                                \
    /* Expand if needed. */                                                     \
    if (self->load == EXPANSION_POINT)                                       \
    {                                                                           \
        status = dynamic_array_##T##_expand(self);                           \
        if (status > 1)                                                         \
        {                                                                       \
            return status; /* pass allocation error code up */                  \
        }                                                                       \
    }                                                                           \
                                                                                \
    /* Move all elements in [i+1..self->size) forward one index. */          \
    array = self->array;                                                     \
    for (idx = self->size; idx > i; idx--)                                   \
    {                                                                           \
        array[idx] = array[idx - 1];                                            \
    }                                                                           \
                                                                                \
    array[idx] = elem;                                                          \
    self->size += 1;                                                         \
    dynamic_array_##T##_recalc_load(self);                                   \
                                                                                \
    return 0;                                                                   \
}

/*
 * Delete the element at the ith index of a dynamic array.
 * Helper method for the remove, remove_at operations.
 *
 * If:
 *   - The dynamic array is valid.
 *   - 0 <= i < self->size.
 * Then:
 *   - The element at the i-th index of the array will be removed.
 *   - All elements higher than the i-th index will be moved an index down.
 *   - The array size will be decremented.
 *   - The array load will be recalculated.
 *   - If the array is sufficiently small after removal (see constants), then
 *     the array will be contracted. The capacity and load will be recalculated.
 *   - 0 is returned.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If the array is contracted and there is an error allocating a new array,
 *     then 1 is returned.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_DELETE_ELEM(T)                                    \
static int dynamic_array_##T##_delete_elem(DynamicArray_##T *self,           \
                                           int i)                               \
{                                                                               \
    int idx;                                                                    \
    T *array;                                                                   \
                                                                                \
    /* Copy every element in [i+1..) back one index. Overwrites array[i] */     \
    array = self->array;                                                     \
    for (idx = i + 1; idx < self->size; idx++)                               \
    {                                                                           \
        array[idx - 1] = array[idx];                                            \
    }                                                                           \
                                                                                \
    /* Contract if necessary. Only contract if array has expanded before */     \
    if (self->load <= CONTRACTION_POINT && self->capacity > INIT_CAPACITY)\
    {                                                                           \
        return dynamic_array_##T##_contract(self);                           \
    }                                                                           \
                                                                                \
    self->size -= 1;                                                         \
    dynamic_array_##T##_recalc_load(self);                                   \
                                                                                \
    return 0;                                                                   \
}

/*
 * Set load equal to size divided by capacity.
 *
 * If:
 *   - The dynamic array is valid.
 * Then:
 *   - load will equal size divided by capacity.
 */
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_RECALC_LOAD(T)                                    \
    static void dynamic_array_##T##_recalc_load(DynamicArray_##T *self)      \
    {                                                                           \
        self->load = ((float)self->size) / ((float)self->capacity);    \
    }

#endif
```

linked_list.h:

```
/*
 * A basic, generic forward-linked-list data structure and relevant operations
 * implemented from scratch in pure, old fashioned C.
 *
 * All functions in this header are prepended with 'linked_list_' to create a
 * psuedo-namespace. The linked list supports operations to: create a new linked
 * list, add an element (at the end or at an index), remove an element (from the
 * end or by key), test if a key is in the list, and determine the size of the
 * list.
 *
 * Written by Max Hanson, June 2019.
 */


#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

#include <stdlib.h> /* For malloc/NULL */


/*
 * A generic forward-linked-list data structure.
 *
 * Note that by 'generic' I mean the key is a void pointer that can point to any
 * data type. It is the client's responsibility to track what data type the
 * linked list's keys are and safely cast them to/from void pointers.
 * Also note that it is necessary that each key in the list points to an object
 * on the heap that was allocated with 'malloc/calloc/realloc'. This is because
 * each key is freed in the linked_list_destruct operation. Undefined behavior
 * will occur if this requirement is not met.
 *
 * A LinkedList is valid if, and only if:
 *   - The key of all nodes is non-null pointer.
 *   - The next node of all nodes points to another node, except the tail node
 *     whose next is null.
 *   - There are no loops in the list.
 *   - The head node leads to the tail node.
 * Note that these operations do not verify linked list validity, but it is
 * guaranteed that the constructor will create a valid linked list and that
 * each operation will leave a valid linked list valid.
 */
typedef struct linked_list_node_tag LinkedListNode;
struct linked_list_node_tag
{
    void *key;
    LinkedListNode *next;
};
typedef struct linked_list_tag
{
    int size;
    LinkedListNode *head;
    LinkedListNode *tail;
} LinkedList;

/*
 * Create a new linked list from a key.
 *
 * Every case complexity: BIG-THETA(1).
 * If:
 *   - The head_key is not NULL.
 * Then:
 *   - A valid LinkedList is returned such that:
 *     - Its head nodes key is the head_key.
 *     - Its head node is its tail node.
 *     - Its size is 1.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If there is not enough space on the heap for a new LinkedList and
 *     LinkedListNode, then NULL is returned.
 */
LinkedList *linked_list_construct(void *head_key);

/*
 * Deallocate a linked list.
 *
 * 
 * Every case runtime: BIG-THETA(n) where n is the size of the list.
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid linked list.
 * Then:
 *   - All keys in the list will be freed.
 *   - All nodes in the list will be freed.
 *   - The linked list itself will be freed.
 *   - The list pointer will be NULL.
 */
void linked_list_destruct(LinkedList *list);

/*
 * Append a key to a linked list.
 *
 * Every case complexity: BIG-THETA(1).
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid LinkedList.
 *   - The key points to the same data type as all nodes of the list.
 * Then:
 *   - A new node is created whose key is The key.
 *   - The lists previous tail will point to this new node.
 *   - The lists tail will point to this new node.
 *   - The lists size will be incremented.
 *   - A positive value is returned.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If there is not enough space on the heap for a new LinkedListNode, then
 *     zero is returned.
 */
int linked_list_add(LinkedList *list, void *key);

/*
 * Add an element to the i-th index of a linked list.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O(n) where n is the number of nodes in the list.
 * Worst case complexity: BIG-THETA(n).
 * Best case complexity: BIG-THETA(1).
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid LinkedList.
 *   - The key points to the same data type as all nodes of the list.
 *   - 0 <= 'i' <= list.size.
 * Then:
 *   - A new node is created whose key is The key.
 *   - This new node will be the i-th node of the list.
 *   - If a new head is added, then the lists head will be updated.
 *   - The lists size will be incremented.
 *   - A positive value is returned.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If there is not enough space on the heap for a new LinkedListNode, then
 *     zero is returned.
 */
int linked_list_add_at(LinkedList *list, void *key, int i);

/*
 * Remove the i-th node of a linked list.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O(n) where n is the number of elements in the list.
 * Worst case complexity: BIG-THETA(n).
 * Best case complexity: BIG-THETA(1).
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid LinkedList.
 *   - 0 <= i < 'list.size'.
 * Then:
 *   - The node previously at the lists i-th index will be removed.
 *   - If the head/tail is removed, then the new head/tail will be updated.
 *   - The lists size will be decremented.
 */
void linked_list_remove_at(LinkedList *list, int i);

/*
 * Remove the first node containing a certain key from a linked list.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O(n) where n is the number of elements in the list.
 * Worst case complexity: BIG-THETA(n).
 * Best case complexity: BIG-THETA(1).
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid LinkedList.
 *   - The key is not NULL.
 * Then:
 *   - If the list contains the key, the first node with the matching key
 *     (comparing addresses) is removed and a positive value is returned.
 *   - If the list doesnt contain the key, then the list is unchanged and zero
 *     is returned.
 */
int linked_list_remove_key(LinkedList *list, void *key);

/*
 * Determine if a linked list contains a key.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O(n) where n is the nubmer of elements in the list.
 * Worst case complexity: BIG-THETA(n).
 * Best case complexity: BIG-THETA(1).
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid LinkedList.
 *   - The key is not NULL.
 * Then:
 *   - If the list contains the key, then a positive value is returned.
 *   - If the list doesnt contain the key then zero is returned.
 */
int linked_list_contains_key(LinkedList *list, void *key);

/*
 * Get the key of the i-th node of a linked list.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O(n) where n is the number of elements in the list.
 * Worst case complexity: BIG-THETA(n).
 * Best case complexity: BIG-THETA(1).
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid LinkedList.
 *   - 0 <= i < list.size
 * Then:
 *   - The key of the i-th node of the list is returned.
 */
void *linked_list_get_key(LinkedList *list, int i);


#endif
```

linked_list.c:

````
/**
 * An implementation of the linked list operations from scratch.
 *
 * See the function definitions in the linked list header for documentation.
 *
 * Written by Max Hanson, June 2019.
 */

#include "linked_list.h"

static LinkedListNode *create_node(void *key);
static void point_to_index(LinkedList *list, LinkedListNode **prev_ptr,
                           LinkedListNode **cursor_ptr, int index);
static void point_to_key(LinkedList *list, LinkedListNode **prev_ptr,
                         LinkedListNode **cursor_ptr, void *key);
static void remove_node(LinkedList *list, LinkedListNode *prev,
                        LinkedListNode *cursor);


LinkedList *linked_list_construct(void *head_key)
{
    LinkedListNode *new_node;
    LinkedList *new_llist;

    new_node = create_node(head_key); 
    new_llist = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    if (new_node == NULL || new_llist == NULL)
    {
        /* Allocation failed. */
        return NULL;
    }
    new_llist->size = 1;
    new_llist->head = new_node;
    new_llist->tail = new_node;

    return new_llist;
}

void linked_list_destruct(LinkedList *list)
{
    LinkedListNode *cursor;
    LinkedListNode *prev;

    /* Step through, freeing each previous. Frees tail too. */
    cursor = list->head;
    prev = NULL;
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        prev = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;

        free(prev->key);
        free(prev);
    }
    free(list);
}

int linked_list_add(LinkedList *list, void *key)
{
    LinkedListNode *new_node;

    new_node = create_node(key);
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    list->tail->next = new_node;
    list->tail = new_node;
    list->size += 1;

    return 1;
}

int linked_list_add_at(LinkedList *list, void *key, int i)
{
    LinkedListNode *new_node;
    LinkedListNode *cursor;
    LinkedListNode *prev;
    int idx;

    new_node = create_node(key);
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    point_to_index(list, &prev, &cursor, i);
    /* Add new_node as new i-th node. */
    if (cursor == list->head)
    {
        /* Adding new head. Prev is null. */
        new_node->next = cursor;
        list->head = new_node;
    }
    if (prev == list->tail)
    {
        /* Adding a new tail. Cursor is null. */
        prev->next = new_node;
        list->tail = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Adding intermediate node. */
        prev->next = new_node;
        new_node->next = cursor;
    }
    list->size += 1;

    return 1;
}

void linked_list_remove_at(LinkedList *list, int i)
{
    LinkedListNode *cursor;
    LinkedListNode *prev;
    int idx;

    /* NOTE assumed that i is within range, no checking. */
    point_to_index(list, &prev, &cursor, i);
    remove_node(list, prev, cursor);
}

int linked_list_remove_key(LinkedList *list, void *key)
{
    LinkedListNode *cursor;
    LinkedListNode *prev;
    int idx;

    point_to_key(list, &prev, &cursor, key);
    if (cursor == NULL)
    {
        /* NOTE null if no matching key. */
        return 0;
    }
    remove_node(list, prev, cursor);
    return 1;
}

int linked_list_contains_key(LinkedList *list, void *key)
{
    LinkedListNode *cursor;
    LinkedListNode *prev;
    int idx;

    point_to_key(list, &prev, &cursor, key);
    return (cursor != NULL); /* NOTE null if no matching key. */
}

void *linked_list_get_key(LinkedList *list, int i)
{
    LinkedListNode *cursor;
    LinkedListNode *prev;
    int idx;

    point_to_index(list, &prev, &cursor, i);

    return cursor->key;
}

/* === HELPER METHODS === */

/*
 * Create a new node on the heap.
 *
 * Every case complexity: O(1).
 * If:
 *   - The key is not NULL.
 * Then:
 *   - A pointer to a node whose key is 'key' and next is NULL is returned.
 * Edge cases:
 *   - If there is not room for a new node on the heap, the NULL is returned.
 */
static LinkedListNode *create_node(void *key)
{
    LinkedListNode *new_node;

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    new_node->key = key;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

/*
 * Point a cursor to a lists i-th node.
 *
 * Note the double pointers used in the arguments. This is so the function can
 * modify the first-level pointer.
 *
 * Every case runtime: O(n) where n is the number of nodes in the list.
 * Worst case runtime: BIG-THETA(n).
 * Best case runtime: BIG-THETA(1).
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid linked list.
 *   - 0 <= index <= list.size
 * Then:
 *   - The cursor will point to the i-th node.
 *   - The prev will point to the (i-1)-th node, or null if cursor is the head.
 *   - If i = list.size: then cursor will be null and prev will be the tail.
 */
static void point_to_index(LinkedList *list, LinkedListNode **prev_ptr,
                           LinkedListNode **cursor_ptr, int index)
{
    int idx;
    LinkedListNode *cursor;
    LinkedListNode *prev;

    /* Point cursor, prev to the correct nodes. */
    idx = 0;
    cursor = list->head;
    prev = NULL;
    while(idx != index)
    {
        prev = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;
        idx++;
    }

    /* Point what the args point to to the correct nodes. */
    (*prev_ptr) = prev;
    (*cursor_ptr) = cursor;
}

/*
 * Point a cursor to the first node in a list containing a key.
 *
 * A node contains a key if they both point to the same location in memory.
 * Note the double pointers used in the arguments. This is so the function can
 * modify the first-level pointer.
 *
 * Every case runtime: O(n) where n is the size of the list.
 * Worst case runtime: BIG-THETA(n).
 * Best case runtime: BIG-THETA(1).
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid linked list.
 *   - The key points to the same type of data as the list.
 * Then:
 *   - If the key is in the list, then the cursor will point to the first node
 *     that contains that key and the prev will point to its previous.
 *   - If the key is not in the list, then the cursor and prev will be NULL.
 */
static void point_to_key(LinkedList *list, LinkedListNode **prev_ptr,
                           LinkedListNode **cursor_ptr, void *key)
{
    LinkedListNode *cursor;
    LinkedListNode *prev;

    /* Point cursor, prev to the correct nodes */
    cursor = list->head;
    prev = NULL;
    while(cursor != NULL && cursor->key != key)
    {
        prev = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    /* Point what the args point to to the correct nodes */
    (*cursor_ptr) = cursor;
    (*prev_ptr) = prev;
}

/*
 * Remove a node from a linked list.
 *
 * Every case runtime: O(1).
 * If:
 *   - The list is a valid list.
 *   - The cursor points to a node in the list.
 *   - The prev points to the node that points to the cursor.
 * Then:
 *   - The list will no longer contain the cursor.
 *   - The lists size will be decremented.
 *   - If the cursor was the lists head/tail, then the head/tail will be updated.
 *   - The cursor will be deallocated.
 */
static void remove_node(LinkedList *list, LinkedListNode *prev,
                        LinkedListNode *cursor)
{
    if (cursor == list->head)
    {
        /* Removing head. Prev is NULL. */
        list->head = cursor->next;
    }
    else if (cursor == list->tail)
    {
        /* Removing tail. */
        prev->next = NULL;
        list->tail = prev;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Removing intermediate node. */
        prev->next = cursor->next;
    }
    free(cursor);
    list->size -= 1;
}
```
````

Comment: `status = dynamic_array_##T##_expand(self);                           \
        if (status > 1)                                                         \
        {                                                                       \
            return status; /* pass allocation error code up */                  \
        }`: Given that the called function only returns 0 or 1, that `if` branch will never be executed. Maybe you wanted `if (status)`?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I think I meant to type `if (status > 0)`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 9):

**- `float`**

`float` constants need the suffix `f`:

```c
static const float  EXPANSION_POINT = 1.0f;
```

if not, you're assigning a `double` constant implicitly converted to `float`.

---

**- functions that accept 0 parameters**

Functions that accept 0 parameters should always be defined as `type foo(void)`

`type foo()` means different things depending on the context.  It is different in prototypes (accept any parameters) and definitions (accept 0 parameters), so it's better to avoid that and explicitly use `(void)`.

---

**- `sizeof(type)` vs `sizeof(*pointer)`**

It's better to use `sizeof(*pointer)` so that if the type of `pointer` ever changes, the code is still valid.

---

**- Be careful with error handling**

It's better to use `sizeof(*pointer)` so that if the type of `pointer` ever changes, the code is still valid.

In this code of yours:

```c
    DynamicArray_##T *self = malloc(sizeof(DynamicArray_##T));      \
    array = malloc(INIT_CAPACITY * sizeof(T));                      \
    if (self == NULL || array == NULL)                              \
    {                                                               \
        return NULL;                                                \
    }
```

Imagine that one of the allocations fails but the other doesn't.

Solution:

```c
    self    = malloc(sizeof(*self));                                \
    if (!self)                                                      \
        return  NULL;                                               \
    array   = malloc(sizeof(*array) * INIT_CAPACITY);               \
    if (!array)                                                     \
        goto err_array;                                             \
...
err_array:                                                          \
    free(self);                                                     \
    return  NULL;                                                   \
```

---

**- Reached end of non-void function**

In the function `DynamicArray_##T   *dynamic_array_##T##_construct(void)` you forgot the final `return` statement.

Fixed:

```c
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_CTOR(T)                    
DynamicArray_##T    *dynamic_array_##T##_construct(void)            \
{                                                                   \
    DynamicArray_##T    *self;                                      \
                                                                    \
    self    = malloc(sizeof(*self));                                \
    if (!self)                                                      \
        return  NULL;                                               \
    self->array = malloc(sizeof(*self->array) * INIT_CAPACITY);     \
    if (!self->array)                                               \
        goto err_array;                                             \
                                                                    \
    self->capacity = INIT_CAPACITY;                                 \
    self->size = 0;                                                 \
    self->load = 0.0;                                               \
                                                                    \
    return  self;                                                   \
                                                                    \
err_array:                                                          \
    free(self);                                                     \
    return  NULL;                                                   \
}
```

---

**- `ptrdiff_t`**

The appropriate type for pointer arithmetics (and a dynamic array is full of that) is `ptrdiff_t`.  Of course `int` will work in almost any case (unless you plan to have an array with more than ~2 thousand million elements), but `ptrdiff_t` helps self-documenting the code.

```c
#include <stddef.h>

static const ptrdiff_t  INIT_CAPACITY = 10;

#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_STRUCT(T)                              \
struct DynamicArrayTag_##T {                                        \
    float       load;                                               \
    ptrdiff_t   size;                                               \
    ptrdiff_t   capacity;                                           \
    T           *array;                                             \
};                                                                  \
typedef struct DynamicArrayTag_##T DynamicArray_##T;
```

---

**- comparing floating-point variables**

There are infinite different real numbers between any two given numbers.  In C, that is not true, because of obvious reasons.  But there are still too many different `float` possible values between *any* two given values.

Comparisons like `if (self->load == EXPANSION_POINT)` are unlikely to work.

Depending on the desired behavior, the solution is easy or not.  In this case it is easy:

```c
if (self->load >= EXPANSION_POINT)
```

---

**- nmemb vs size** (This is somewhat personal; feel free to disagree)

There is a slight difference between the terms size and nmemb.

`size` is a name normally used to mean absolute size in Bytes.  Its natural type is `size_t`.

`nmemb` is a name normally used to mean **n**umber of **memb**ers of an array.  Its natural type is `ptrdiff_t`, although `size_t` is not uncommon to see (sadly).

So, I would change the `struct` this way:

```c
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_STRUCT(T)                              \
struct DynamicArrayTag_##T {                                        \
    float       load;                                               \
    ptrdiff_t   nmemb;                                              \
    ptrdiff_t   capacity;                                           \
    T           *array;                                             \
};                                                                  \
typedef struct DynamicArrayTag_##T DynamicArray_##T;
```

---

**- `double` vs `float`**

Unless you have a very good reason, always use `double`.

It's usually faster, and has a lot more precission.  Only some embedded systems should use `float`.  Or one can also use `float` for huge arrays of floating-point numbers, where precission is not important, and cache/RAM speed is a problem.

```c
#define EXPANSION_POINT     (1.0) /* load > this -> array expands */
#define CONTRACTION_POINT   (0.3) /* load < this -> array contracts */
/* Expanded capacity = this * old capacity */
#define EXPANSION_FACTOR    (2.0)
/* Contracted capacity = this * old capacity */
#define CONTRACTION_FACTOR  (0.5)

#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_STRUCT(T)                              \
struct DynamicArrayTag_##T {                                        \
    double      load;                                               \
    ptrdiff_t   nmemb;                                              \
    ptrdiff_t   capacity;                                           \
    T           *array;                                             \
};                                                                  \
typedef struct DynamicArrayTag_##T DynamicArray_##T;
```

---

**- `EXPANSION_POINT`**

Given the instability of floating-point arithmetics, I would set the expansion point a bit lower than `1.0` (maybe `0.85`).

An even better option, if you want it to be `1` is to use the integer values directly (and delete `EXPANSION_POINT`):

```c
if (self->size == self->capacity)
        // Expand
```

---

Fixed code sample:

```c
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_INSERT_ELEM(T)             
static int dynamic_array_##T##_insert_elem(DynamicArray_##T *self,  \
                                            T elem, ptrdiff_t i)    \
{                                                                   \
    ptrdiff_t   j;                                                  \
    int         status;                                             \
                                                                    \
    /* Expand if needed. */                                         \
    if (self->size == self->capacity) {                             \
        status = dynamic_array_##T##_expand(self);                  \
        if (status)                                                 \
            return  status;                                         \
    }                                                               \
                                                                    \
    for (j = self->nmemb; j > i; j--)                               \
        self->array[j] = self->array[j - 1];                        \
    self->array[j] = elem;                                          \
    self->nmemb++;                                                  \
    dynamic_array_##T##_recalc_load(self);                          \
                                                                    \
    return  0;                                                      \
}
```

---

Comment: All great points. Thanks for reading my code :)!

Comment: "Functions that accept 0 parameters should always be defined as type foo(void)" --> Clarity: Function _definition_ a `foo() { ... }` is the same as `foo(void) { ... }` - so that is only a style difference.  Still since it is a difference in a _declaration_ the advice is reasonable: use `(void)`.  UV

Comment: @chux That's what I say in the next paragraph (sorry if it's not very clear). I think I learnt that from you a few months ago :). Btw, what does UV mean?

Comment: Cacahuete Frito: Up-vote

Answer (score 1):

First impressions: I like the comments that clearly specify preconditions and postconditions - very valuable in C!  One thing that wasn't clear was the meaning of the return value from the insert/add/remove methods - is that the number of elements added/removed?

It would be nice to have a list of all the functions at the top of the file (I was surprised to find no accessor to return the size of a dynamic array).

It's a shame there's no simple `main()` included.

---

A limitation of pasting type names to create identifiers is that it requires typedefs for types such as `long long` or `struct foo` or `char*`.  We can probably live with that.

---

Here's a memory leak:

> ```
> LinkedListNode *new_node;
> LinkedList *new_llist;
>
> new_node = create_node(head_key); 
> new_llist = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
> if (new_node == NULL || new_llist == NULL)
> {
>     /* Allocation failed. */
>     return NULL;
> }
> ```

If one of the allocations succeeds and the other fails, we never free the successful one, and lose our reference to it.

Thankfully, `free()` will do the right thing when given a null pointer, so we can unconditionally free both pointers:

```
LinkedListNode *const new_node = create_node(head_key); 
LinkedList *const new_llist = malloc(sizeof *new_llist);

if (new_node == NULL || new_llist == NULL) {
    /* Allocation failed. */
    free(new_node);
    free(new_llist);
    return NULL;
}
```

---

A nicety: it may simplify calling code if it can accept a null pointer instead of a list:

```
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_DTOR(T)                            \
    void dynamic_array_##T##_destruct(DynamicArray_##T *self)   \
    {                                                           \
        if (self) {                                             \
            free(self->array);                                  \
            free(self);                                         \
        }                                                       \
    }
```

This makes it behave more like `free()` causing less surprise to users.

---

I don't think there's much to be gained by having `load` as a member, given that it can always be obtained from `size` and `capacity`.

---

We can make the expand/contract functions much more efficient, by using `realloc()` instead of `malloc()` and copy every time:

```
#define DEFINE_DYNAMIC_ARRAY_EXPAND(T)                                  \
    static int dynamic_array_##T##_expand(DynamicArray_##T *self)       \
    {                                                                   \
        size_t new_capacity = EXPANSION_FACTOR * (self->capacity);      \
        T *new_array = realloc(self->array, new_capacity * sizeof (T)); \
        if (!new_array) {                                               \
            /* Return and do not alter original array. */               \
            return 1;                                                   \
        }                                                               \
                                                                        \
        self->array = new_array;                                        \
        self->capacity = new_capacity;                                  \
        dynamic_array_##T##_recalc_load(self);                          \
        return 0;                                                       \
    }
```

`realloc()` only needs to copy data if it couldn't extend the existing allocation.

The `contract()` function has almost exactly the same code, with only a different `new_capacity` calculation (and perhaps should be merged).

On a related note, instead of loops like this:

> ```
> /* Move all elements in [i+1..self->size) forward one index. */          \
> array = self->array;                                                     \
> for (idx = self->size; idx > i; idx--)                                   \
> {                                                                           \
>     array[idx] = array[idx - 1];                                            \
> }                                                                           \
> ```

we could save both code and CPU time by using `memmove()` (untested):

```
    /* Move all elements in [i+1..self->size) forward one index. */ \
    memmove(self->array + i + 1, self->array + i,                   \
            (self->size - i) * sizeof *self->array);                \
```

And in the `delete_elem()`:

```
    /* Copy every element in [i+1..) back one index. Overwrites array[i] */ \
    memmove(self->array + i, self->array + i + 1,                   \
            (self->size - i) * sizeof *self->array);                \
```

---

We have unused local variables called `idx` in several functions: `linked_list_add_at()`, `linked_list_remove_at()`, `linked_list_remove_key()`, `linked_list_contains_key()`, `linked_list_get_key()`.

The dynamic array `construct` declaration ought to be a prototype (explicitly declare `(void)` = no arguments, rather than `()` = unspecified arguments).

Make `INIT_CAPACITY` an unsigned type to prevent unexpected promotion when multiplying by `size_t`.   Using `double` rather than `float` for the other constants reduces compiler warnings, too.

Comment: I already mentioned that one (there: Be careful with error handling);  although maybe I should have explained it a bit more :)

Comment: Ah, I missed that, because you saw it in a different function.  But we have different mitigations, so both answers have value, I think.